# How to Create a Google Drive Index

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

I have a Google Drive drive with multiple folders and subfolders

I want to make an Excel index that contains a table of the folder name, and the path of the folder (its web address)

I saw that there was a solution [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/19854-list-files-in-google-drive-folder), but I do not know how to use it, or it does not suit me.